# why the results are all 5?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function init() {    
    var pArry = document.getElementsByTagName("p");    
    for( var i=0; i<pAry.length; i++ ) {    
         pArry[i].onclick = function() {    
         alert(i);    
    } 
  }
}
</script> 
</head> 
<body onload="init();"> 
<p>test 0</p> 
<p>test 1</p> 
<p>test2</p> 
<p>test3</p> 
<p>test4</p>
```

why the results are all  5? i want the reault is (0,1,2....).

Answer (score 1):

It's referencing `i`, not the value of `i` when that function is created. Try this to freeze the value of `i`:

```
function init() {    
    var pArray = document.getElementsByTagName("p");    
    for( var i=0; i<pAry.length; i++ ) {    
        (function(i) {
            pArray[i].onclick = function() {    
                alert(i);    
            };
        })(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't exactly freeze the value of `i` -- rather this creates a *new* `i` (via new function-scope) for each closure which has the initial value of the current `i` (from the loop) when the outer anonymous function is applied. I think not re-using `i` might make the intent more clear.